# PHP session seems to be closing or is lost on login and redirect on Slim framework

Tags: php, session, slim

Hello I am new to programming in php, I am using Slim framework but I want to work with native php sessions. I've been encountering a problem where my session seems to be closing or is lost once I login and redirect to another html page.

I am getting an error

`Slim\Slim:: HandleErrors(8, undefined index..., 450, Array)`

I have 2 archives an `index.php` and a `sesion.php`.

Title `session.php`

```
session_name('session');
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
     echo '<script> window.location="index.html"; </script>';
}
```

Title `index.php`. I am going to skip all other requires and includes.

```
include 'sesion.php';

$app->post('/login', function () use($servername, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword) 
{
// Some Code
$_SESSION ['user'] = $result[0]['username'];
}

$app->get('/projects/all', function () use($servername, $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpassword)
{
// Some code
echo ($_SESSION['user']); //line 450
return;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `echo '<script> window.location="index.html"; </script>';` use a header instead. This could be the issue.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone a header?

Comment: Your also using `include 'sesion.php';` when it should be `include 'session.php';`.

Comment: `header('Location: index.html');`

Comment: sorry i mispelled here but in my code is fine. @LawrenceCherone. changed the the window location for the header and i am still getting the same error